# how can I echo/print specific lines from a bash variable

Tags: bash, variables, debian

I am trying to print specific lines from a multi-line bash variable. I've found the following:

```
while read line; do echo LINE: "$line"; done <<< "$x"
```

where x would be the variable, but that simply prints out all lines instead of just a single one (say line 1 for instance). How could I go about adapting this to print out a specific line instead of all of them? (would like to avoid having to write the variable to a file instead)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To print the Nth line:

```
sed -n ${N}p <<< "$x"
```

or (more portably):

```
sed -n ${N}p << EOF
$x
EOF
```

or

```
echo "$x" | sed -n "$N"p
```

or

```
echo "$x" | sed -n ${N}p
```

or (for the specific case N==3)

```
echo "$x" | sed -n 3p
```

or

```
while read line; do echo LINE: "$line"; done <<< "$x" | sed -n ${N}p
```

or

```
while read line; do echo LINE: "$line"; done << EOF | sed -n ${N}p
$x
EOF
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks! ended up going with the echo "$x" | sed -n "$N"p option

Answer (score 11):

You can split it into an array like:

```
IFS=$'\n' lines=($x)
```

Then you can access any line by indexing the array, e.g.:

```
echo ${lines[1]}
```

(of course, `lines[0]` is "line 1").

Comment: thanks! had done that with an array one a while back but could not remember what I had done for the life of me

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use an array for some reason, and you want to do this within bash rather than by spawning an external tool like `sed`, you can simply count lines:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ x=$'one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\n'
[ghoti@pc ~]$ n=3
[ghoti@pc ~]$ for (( c=0; c<n; c++ )); do read line; done <<< "$x"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo $line
three
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Or using one fewer variable:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ n=2
[ghoti@pc ~]$ for (( ; n>0; n-- )); do read line; done <<< "$x"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo $line
two
```

These methods use what's sometimes called a "three expression for loop".  It's a construct that's common in many languages, from bash to awk to perl to PHP to C (but not Python!).  Getting to know them will help your programming in general.

Though ... you probably don't want to be using bash to learn "real" programming. :-)